# VUEJS2.0.0.rc.2 vm.$destroy(true) does not work

Tags: vue.js

With vuejs2.0.0.rc.2, i can not destroy a component with 
    
    `this.$destroy(true)`

Although the event listener removed, but the dom node is not removed from dom.
Here is the live code:
https://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/apokjqxx/

Can you have a check

Answer (score 0):

from vuejs author's comment : 
The vuejs2.0 does not support this $destroy(true) true parameter anymore.
we must remove the dom node ourselves.